# Какие компоненты класса могут быть виртуальными?

Tags: c#

Какие компоненты класса могут быть виртуальными?

Comment: Первый же результат по "c# virtual" - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9fkccyh4.aspx

Comment: @Monk: Оформите в виде ответа? Пусть гугл ведёт сюда.

Comment: @VladD для полноценного ответа я даже не знаю чего писать

Comment: @Monk: Ну, весь список (методы, свойства, индексаторы и события), и ссылку на документацию. Вроде больше ничего не нужно. Можно пример объявления разве что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Виртуальными могут быть:

- Методы
- Свойства
- Индексаторы
- События

[Справка msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9fkccyh4.aspx)